# Google still detects my voice when I turn off Assistant

Tags: google-assistant

After I have disabled Google Assistant in the Google settings the phone continues to show a black bar displayed with an icon of a microphone, with the words:

> Say "Hey Google"

If I say "Hey Google" it detects my voice and shows a new window. I was just wondering why this is happening if Assistant has been disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Police blog [fully disable OK Google listening android phone](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/08/28/fully-disable-ok-google-listening-android-phone/) suggests a couple of ways :

1. Disable the Google Assistant and Voice Match

> .... doesn't actually stop your phone from listening for commands; it only prevents it from reacting to them

2. Deny Google microphone permission, which is a better option. Depending on your Android version, it will take some searching to find the app setting. It will throw up a warning, but that can be ignored. Note that Google related functionality using microphone may be affected.